# SQL Server 2005: Full-text search, order by matches

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, order-by

Is it possible to do a full-text search in SQL Server 2005, ordering on the number of matches?

For example, let's say I have the following products for sale.

```
Tennis Racquets
Tennis Balls
Footballs
Hockey Sticks
```

If I do a search like:

```
select * from products where freetext(productname,'tennis ball')
```

The first three results would be returned as they all have "tennis" or "ball".  I would like to order the results so that "tennis balls", the one with two matches instead of one, is on top.

Is there a "match ratio" column, or something that can be used to rank how close the match was?  Is there a better way to do a full-text search that would allow for ranking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try [`FREETEXTTABLE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177652%28v=sql.90%29.aspx):

```
SELECT ft.[Rank], p.*
FROM dbo.products AS p 
INNER JOIN FREETEXTTABLE(products, productname, 'tennis ball') AS ft  
ON ft.key_column = p.key_column  
ORDER BY ft.[Rank] DESC;
```

Comment: That is exactly what I'm looking for.  Thank you!